# P2P Connections

Tags: network, networking, network-core, point-to-point

Hey there I am a noob in the field of networking and I have a confusion: What is the difference between **point-to-point** and **end-to-end connection ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of point-to-point as one straw. Two ends of one straw are P2P connections.

And end-to-end as 100 different straws connected to each other forming one very large straw. Two ends of the very long straw are end-to-end connections.

Answer (score 3):

**End to End** mean communication Between Two devices or application. It Simply if you are calling to your friend via Skype it is end to end communication. It does not care about what is in the middle.

**P2P** mean Point to Point Link- It is layer 2 Connectivity between two devices. It can Use PPP or HDLC Protocol.

Comment: Other protocols are also used on point to point links, for example X.21 and SLIP.

Comment: Also keep in mind, in today's switched/muxed world, p-t-p is rarely actually p-t-p -- there isn't a wire directly between two devices. (it only *appears* to be)

Answer (score 1):

A point-to-point connections is a dedicated communication link between two systems processes.

An end-to-end connection refers to a connection between two systems across a switched network.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much relation between these terms.

The **end-to-end principle** is used in network stack design: all functions relevant to the application level are located at the end nodes in a communication. All intermediate nodes - gateways, routers, switches - are application-agnostic. This simplifies network architecture and devices immensely. The end-to-end principle breaks when NA(P)T is used.

An end-to-end communication is that between the end hosts.

**Point-to-point** communication is between exactly two peers. Most often, this term is used on the physical layer when interfaces are used that can only connect two nodes, e.g. a simple serial interface, a telephone line or similar. *Point-to-point* is also used for /31 link segments where exactly two IP nodes can connect.

Most networks use point-to-multipoint links where any node can talk to any other node that is connected, e.g. the ubiquitous Ethernet that uses MAC addresses to direct traffic within a local segment.